# Control System that unlike subversion allows me to rename, delete folders as I want

Tags: tortoisesvn

I like subversion except for folders renaming, deleting : it's such a nightmare for me as I do this a lot that I want to drop off subversion for something else as close as Subversion but which can stand folders renaming, deleting moving under Explorer without obligating me to launch a special command.

Is there an alternative ?

It's several times I create a new repo after subversion corruption, now it says the working copy lock seems to be broken. I'm exhausted :)

Update: for Windows ;)

Answer (score 1):

For the Mac there are two great options for what I think you are looking for. First there is [Tower for Mac](http://www.git-tower.com/) and the there is [Versions for Mac](http://www.versionsapp.com/) which really is great if you want to step away from Github and Svn. So either try find the Windows Alternative to these two or switch over the the Mac way of life. Best wishes. Good luck

Comment: In truth I have also a Mac for developing on iPhone so I will try your suggestion. For now on I need for Windows.

Comment: OK I'm searching for a clone of Tower for Mac on Windows.